# How to test function that changes file content (Jest)

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

For example i have a function in module "updater.js" that changes "main.js" file content, how i can test this behavior with jest?

Updater function code:

```
function update() {
  ..... update main.js content
}

module.exports = update
```

Project structure:

```
myProject
  updater.js
  main.js <-this file changes if call "update" function
```

I want to place the "main.js" test file in "fixtures" folder, then, during testing, i want to copy this file to some "tmp" directory, run my function (updater.js) on this file, and at the end of testing delete "tmp" folder, which contains changed "main.js". How to realize this with Jest?
P.S
Excuse me for my English :)

UPDATE
In reality, the "update" function must find the closest "package.json" file, and update some info of this file. (it uses process.cwd())

I have been tried to use library "fsify" to store fake project folder with "package.json" file in "tmp" folder and then delete it after testing. But can i change process.cwd during testing?

Comment: Did you try implementing the logic you describe? What happened? To help avoid XY problems, the context that requires rewriting main would also be helpful.

Comment: I will update question.